# OpenVPN Connection No Outgoing

Tags: server, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to connect to a VPN from Ubuntu 16.04 server edition (no GUI).

I use the downloaded configuration and connect with `sudo openvpn - - config path/to/.ovpn`

This seems to work fine, no errors and I get a `tun` interface. But I cannot seem to access external urls.

E.g. `ping google.com` results in a long pause then `ping: unknown host google.com`

A simple sendmail command fails saying it cannot connect to SMTP server (external)

Dyndns client fails to update, presumably as it can't connect with the service provider.

If I disconnect the openvpn connection the above all works fine.

I have enabled through traffic on my router (virgin media superhub) to no avail. Do I need to do any port forwarding? But none of the guides say to do so...

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8 when connected to the VPN?  Does your OPenVPN connection assign a DNS server for it to say "Go query through this"?  (which is why you can't ping `google.com` possibly, because you can't resolve its dns)

Comment: Aha... Yes I can ping 8.8.8.8! But I am unsure what that means. Shouldn't the VPN provider's config (ovpn) file take care of DNS? How do I check. Thanks for the positive answer... I'm a step closer. Funny how on GUI desktop I never had this problem

Comment: Did you set up the VPN server?

Comment: No, it's a paid for service. Buffered VPN

Comment: When on the VPN, use `dig +short A google.com` or `nslookup google.com`.  Do you get any type of data back or does it just either do nothing or error out

Comment: Hi Thomas, same thing `nslookup google.com                                        ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Comment: I know this sounds repetitive, but does `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8` return anything useful other than "timed out"?

Comment: When connected to VPN, `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.18.142`

Comment: Is there anything output in `cat /etc/resolv.conf` containing a `nameserver` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to my lack of ability to follow simple instructions it seems, reviewing the setup instructions by the provider, I seemed to have missed a vital step which was to add a script to my .ovpn config to run `update-resolv-conf` This then fixed it.

Apologies for time wasting and many thanks to Thomas for his help and persistance.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a DNS problem.

As was tested by the OP in comments, data can go out to the Internet from over the VPN, so the issue is that it's not getting a DNS server with which to query.  We've also confirmed that DNS lookups can be done outbound.  So we just need to make sure the system can always reach a DNS server.

In your `/etc/resolv.conf` and when you are connected to your VPN, there should be something like this at the very least (IP addresses may differ!) in the file:

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

If not, then we need to make sure you have a DNS server set so you can resolve domain names.  So, replace the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` with the following (Google DNS):

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and then try and use the Internet normally over the VPN.

If you do this and it doesn't work because `/etc/resolv.conf` keeps getting overwritten, then you may wish to consider forcing it to be unchangeable with `sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`.  **If you are absolutely certain that you won't have to change your DNS servers, then do not make this change**, because you will run into issues with DHCP or such trying to set DNS nameservers and failing because nothing can edit `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: OK, you might want to kill me now...found out the problem. I had to add some lines to my .ovpn config to run `update-resolv-conf` as per instructions from my provider....missed that somehow, works now. <insert embarrased smiley face> Thank you so much for your effort though, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @j0nr Add that as an answer and accept it.  You can say you made a mistake following the providers instructions, and be no worse off :)

Comment: Have the same problem, and modifying the xxx.ovpn file with update-resolv-conf did not help. It looks like my resolv.conf file is a symlink with a warning that it is being overwritten anyway, and the content is nameserver 127.0.1.1. This is on 16.04 version of Ubuntu. N.B. the vpn connection process seems to do everything it is supposed to do (establish connection, set up tun0, manipulate dns, etc.) but still not getting out to the Internet.